# 以后我少的一点儿 what does this mean?

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm doing some anki revision when this popped up. I understand the characters in isolation, but can't understand the meaning of the sentence. Google translates this to "from now on I'll have less" which I guess the characters are sort of there for that. Just feels like I'm missing something. Any advice on how this fits together?

Cheers,

Comment: can you provide more context?

Comment: This phrase/sentence does not make sense at all. Need more clues. What is "anki revision" about?

Comment: Possibly a typo. If one swaps 少 and 的, the sentence would be 以后我的少一点儿, which in oral language means "From now on please give me a bit less."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is this segment was taken from a longer sentence incorrectly, resulting in a fragment that makes no sense. As a language exercise, lets see if we can find a possible source of this fragment and add on to the ends to make a logical statement:

((以後我少的一點兒 ...... spoiler I couldn't do it.  However lets logically walk through the attempt, maybe it will help with understanding the pieces better(๑╹ω╹๑ )))

以後我 is a logical start to a phrase, and would simply mean "afterwards I (blank)"  It is common to have whatever event it is after stated prior to this part of the phrase, example 打針以後我 "after getting the shot I".

So our reconsruction so far is XX以後我 "after XX I..."  Lets continue with the end 的一點兒:

一點兒 is a completely normal phrase, meaning "a little".  However how normal is it to come after 的？ I couldn't find a single use.  It has to be a little bit *something* and 的 structure makes no sense here.  But maybe the whole fragment isn't lost, and 少的 is some kinda typo.

for now lets tentatively make our original sentence XX以後我((手民之誤))一點兒XX "After XX I ((typo)) a little bit XX" This is a totally plausible sentence.... although its missing more than it has which bodes very poorly for us.

Here is the nail in the coffin.  少的 itself makes no sense, only common typo would be 小的 or some other de, but all make equally little sense.  In order to make this fragment logical it needs a complete revamp and rewording. Just for satisfaction lets fill the blanks with a logical version: 打針以後我比你一點兒也不覺得累。"After getting the shot, compared to you I wasn't a bit tired."

So yeah, as others said, this makes no sense, and logic dictates its just a wierd ungrammatical string.  A forceful translation is "afterwards I a few some a little bit".  Makes as much sense in english as chinese and no saving it.  I recommend vetting your other flashcards for quality, and hope this exercise helped explain HOW its wrong so the WHY it makes no sense is clear-- and helps you to better recognize those things yourself

（＾_＾）